# How did this Mercy get 104% Kill Participation?

Tags: overwatch

They didn't really do anything but play the standard support role, healing and buffing players as needed. The only thing I can think of that might have caused this is Genji's reflect.

[image]

Comment: Speaking as a long time TF2 medic, she deserved it.

Comment: "heal and buff players as needed" well... thats exactly what she is supposed to do, right? How does that qualify as "didn't really do anything"?

Comment: I meant to say 'didn't really do anything special', as in played a support role. I've seen many people play Mercy and do nothing but try to get kills.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

<s>You can get both an elimination and a defensive assist if you damage an enemy that gets finished off by a teammate you're healing. With that it's possible to exceed 100% kill participation.</s>

I'm not deleting that for posterity, but it's completely wrong, and the real reason is that if someone destroys Torbjorn's turret (possibly Widow's mines, Junrkat's deployables, Mei's wall, and others, but I can't test) while being healed or buffed by Mercy, they won't get an elimination, but Mercy will gain an assist.

Comment: Does this mean it's theoretically possible to get 200%?

Comment: @acbabis Yes, but that means your whole team is huddling around you and only shooting targets you've already injured, and only after you've healed/buffed them. So it's not practical at all.

Comment: Would healing and damage boosting someone while they kill an enemy also count as double?

Comment: @Bonnici You cant do both of those at once.

Comment: @Matt I mean if you heal while they are damaging someone *then* damage boost them when they kill the same enemy.

Comment: @Bonnici Oh. Thats a good question.