# How was I able to attain more than 100% kill participation with D. Va?

Tags: overwatch

A little while ago, I managed to obtain a 104% kill participation while playing a Quick Play game on Lijiang Tower. (It was on July 25, 2016, in the event that was a bug patched afterwards).

How could I attain such a score? If it was accuracy, I could understand that I could hit more than one target per shot, but as far as kill participation goes, I'm not really sure how it was possible.

Screenshot below (from shadowplay video)

[image: 104% kill participation as D. Va]

I can upload the video for the whole game if needed. It wasn't brilliant but maybe it could help explain how this came to be

Link to the video of the complete game

Comment: Considering voting to close as a duplicate, but it's a different hero, and D.Va wouldn't be getting heal assists: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/269240/108003

Comment: What map was it? Also Quick Play or Competitive?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer QuickPlay, on LijiangTower

Comment: Did anyone on the other team leave during the game and get filled by someone else?

Comment: @Dragonrage 3 people left and one joined, all of them in the last 10 seconds but no kills were made

Comment: Added the video of the complete game, youtube is still processing it, and thus only the lowest quality is available for now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is due to someone leaving and another person joining and ending the game with fewer deaths than the other person had when they left. From what I can tell, it seems to calculate the kill participation percentage by `# of eliminations you get / total # of deaths other team has`. So if you have 100% kill participation, and the person on the other team who has the most deaths leaves, and someone else joins and ends the games with less deaths and you keep your kill participation close to 100% after that, your kill participation would be over 100%. This would also occur if someone left and no one replaced them. I have noticed a jump in kill participation when this happens, and a number of other people report this happening to them.

Comment: If your formula is correct, this is probably the correct answer, I'll try to ask Blizzard via their support/twitter to double check

Comment: I asked Blizzard CS/Overwatch on twitter, we'll see what they say about it. Validating your answer in the mean time

Comment: This has been fixed in [the upcoming patch](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20243886#patchnotes): `Fixed a bug that allowed the kill participation metric to go above 100 percent`

Answer (score 1):

Any kills done after a round ends in Control Point maps such as Lijiang Tower count for personal stats, but not for the match's stats. So an elimination you made after a round's end will increase your own eliminations, but not the team's total eliminations.

With that it's possible to pad "card stats", making it possible to achieve kill participation higher than 100%.

Comment: This sounds totally plausible, but could use some evidence.

Comment: Sounds plausible but it was not the case this time, it seems there was no kill between the point capture and the end of the round

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I wasn't even sure this was right, it's most likely Dragonrage's explanation then.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Not a problem, I kinda remember reading something like that here on arqade :) And I didn't post the video when you answered.
Still a plausible explanation